# How to put string values into string array obtained from user using while loop

Tags: java, while-loop

I am trying to get values from user and storing those values in string array. It can be achieved by for loop easily. But need to accomplish it using while loop. Help me out to solve this.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
int testCases = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine()); 
String[] arr1 = new String[testCases]; 

for(int i=0; i<testCases;i++) {
    String s = in.nextLine(); 
    arr1[i]=s; 
} 

for(int i=0; i<testCases;i++) { 
    try {
        Pattern.compile(arr1[i]); 
        System.out.println("Valid"); 
    } catch(Exception e) { 
        System.out.println("Invalid"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  int testCases = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
  String[] arr1 = new String[testCases];
  
  for(int i=0; i<testCases;i++) {
   String s = in.nextLine();
   arr1[i]=s;
  }
  for(int i=0; i<testCases;i++) {
   try {
    Pattern.compile(arr1[i]);
    System.out.println("Valid");
   }
   catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Invalid");
   }
  }

Comment: Put your code in the question

Comment: @AravindArun Please update your question with the code (and properly format it), instead of putting it in comment

Comment: Just add some prompting and your code will be better, but what are you trying to do with `Pattern`

Comment: sorry i'm new to stack overflow. @Scary Wombat thanks for updating the code in question

Comment: So what's the actual problem?  `for(A;B;C) { D }` can be (mostly) translated to `A; while(B) { D; C;}`.

Comment: @ScaryWombat i am just validating Pattern syntax obtained from user

Comment: @AdrianShum yes need to execute the same code using while loop

Comment: @AravindArun That's what I said in the comment already:  You can translate `for` loop to `while` loop in very straight-forward way

Answer (score 0):

Just using while loop:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
int testCases = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine()); 
String[] arr1 = new String[testCases];
int i = 0; 
int n = testCases;
while(i < n)
{
    String s = in.nextLine(); 
    arr1[i] = s;
    testCases--;
    i++;
} 
while(testCases < n)
{ 
    try { 
      Pattern.compile(arr1[testCases]); 
      System.out.println("Valid"); 
    } catch(Exception e) { 
      System.out.println("Invalid"); 
    }
    testCases++;
    i--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As C/C++/Java-101: For loop and While loop can be (mostly) inter-translated by:

```
for (initialization; condition; increment) {
  logic;
}
```

is (mostly) equivalent to

```
initialization;
while(condition) {
    logic;
    increment;
}
```

(the biggest difference is how `continue` behave. However it is not affecting you in this case)

Answer (score 0):

You can again set the value of i to 0 before running second while loop.

```
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
        int testCases = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine()); 
        String[] arr1 = new String[testCases]; 
        int i=0;
        while(i<testCases)
        {
            String s = in.nextLine(); 
            arr1[i]=s; 
            i++;
        } 
        i=0;
        while(i<testCases)
        { 
            try { Pattern.compile(arr1[i]); 
            System.out.println("Valid"); 
            } catch(Exception e) 
            { 
                System.out.println("Invalid"); 
            }
            i++;
        }
```